# Magento 2.3.4 Load Product by id by any method

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2 there is more than one method to get product by id. Anyone show me how to get product y in any of the method step by step include files name nd path used.

Answer (score 4):

1. Inject `Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface` in your constructor and assign it to a variable in the class.

```php
 $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
```

2. Get the product by it's SKU -

```php
 $product = $this->productRepository->get($productSku);
```

3. Get the product by it's ID -

```php
$product = $this->productRepository->getById($id);
```

This is the recommended way to access a data from database in **Magento**.

Answer (score 1):

Add block and Controller file  like this

```
protected $_productloader;

public function __construct(
    ........................................
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader,
    ........................................
) {
    ........................................
    $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
    ........................................
}
public function getLoadProduct($id)
{
    return $this->_productloader->create()->load($id);
}
```

In controler and block you can call using

```
$product_id = 45;
$data = $this->getLoadProduct($product_id);
print_r($data->getData());
```

In phtml file call

```
$product_id = 45;
$data = $block->getLoadProduct($product_id);
print_r($data->getData());
```

block and phtml link like this (add your block file path )

```
<block class="VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\YourBlockName" name="prd.data" template="VendoreName_ModuleName::yourfilname.phtml" >
```

Answer (score 0):

***Object method***

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
```

***Factory Method***

```
<?php
namespace Test\Module\Block;

class Product extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

  protected $_productloader;  


  public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader

    ) {


        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function getLoadProduct($id)
    {
        return $this->_productloader->create()->load($id);
    }

}
```

***phtml file code***

```
$product=$this->getLoadProduct(20);
echo $product->getName();


<?php
    namespace Test\Module\Block;
    use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
    class Product extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
     {
          protected $productRepository; 
          protected $_storeManager; 

          public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
            ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
          ) {
              parent::__construct($context);

              $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
          }
          public function getProduct()
          {

              $productId=1;
              return $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I used the easiest way to get the `ProductName` by `ID`.

use this code in your `Controller`  `<vendor name>/<module>/Controller/Index/Index.php`

```php
<?php
namespace <vendor name>\<module>\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
 protected $_pageFactory,$productId=731,$productModel;
 public function __construct(Context $context,Product $productModel)
{
 parent::__construct($context);
 $this->productModel = $productModel;
 $this->getProductModel();
}
 public function execute()
{
 return $this->_pageFactory->create();
}
 public function getProductModel()
{
 $product=$this->productModel->load($this->productId);
 echo $product->getName();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Vendor\Module\ViewModel;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Index implements 
  \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ProductFactory
     */
    private $productFactory;

    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $productRepository;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var Registry
     */
    private $registry;

    /**
     * @var CurrencyFactory
     */
    private $currencyFactory;

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    private $collectionProductFactory;

    /**
     * @param ProductFactory $productFactory
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param Registry $registry
     * @param CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionProductFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
       ProductFactory $productFactory,
       ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
       StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
       Registry $registry,
       CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory,
       CollectionFactory $collectionProductFactory

    ){
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->currencyFactory = $currencyFactory;
        $this->collectionProductFactory = $collectionProductFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param $id
     * @return Product
     */
    public function loadProduct($id)
    {
        return $this->productFactory->create()->load($id);
    }

    /**
     * @return ProductInterface
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function getProductId($productId)
    {
        return $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function getStoreId()
    {
        return $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {
        return $this->registry->registry('current_product');
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function getProductCollection(){

        $productCollection = $this->collectionProductFactory->create();
        $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $productCollection->load();
        return $productCollection;
    }

}
```