# How to add Product name on current product page or any page in Magento 2?

Tags: product, magento2.3

I'm using magento 2.3, may i ask how can i made product name on others page. 
Beacuse i tried this code but not working. Anyone can help? thank you!!

```
<?php echo $_product->getName(); ?>
```

Comment: ok so you need any product name anywhere?

Comment: try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/307041/magento-2-3-4-load-product-by-id-by-any-method/307052#307052

Comment: I just want to display same product name on product view page on footer part, look like breadcrumbs, can you help, thank you! @sarveshDineshkumarPatel

Comment: I just want to display same product name on product view page on footer part, look like breadcrumbs, can you help, thank you! @Msquare

Comment: okay so you want in footer, can you provide me file name?

Comment: please put my answer code in your file.

Comment: or let me know how you need it so I can do like that

Comment: or share me your footer code you code so I check and I will update it.

Comment: i tried in name.phtml i can use this code <?php echo $_product->getName(); ?>
 working, but it just working on header, i want to copy this code working on same page footer part. @sarveshDineshkumarPatel

Comment: are you share it with me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105633/discussion-between-sarvesh-dineshkumar-patel-and-niceonelee).

Comment: i add post here please check it. and inform me it;s works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please you get by-product Id.

```
$productId = "10"; //Product Id

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);

echo $product->getName(); //Get Product Name
```

Or try for the current page.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$appState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');

$registry = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Registry');
$currentProduct = $registry->registry('current_product');
echo $currentProduct->getName() . '<br />';
```

I hope it is useful to you.

Comment: I just want to display same product name on product view page on footer part, look like breadcrumbs, can you help, thank you!

Comment: yes just use my code and set that in a variable and put it as PHP code.

Comment: but not a one product, is want to all product, auto to change. if just setting one Product Id just display one product name.

Comment: ok try second code so you get exact

Answer (score 0):

You need to load product to get product name

With Object Manager

```
$productId = "10"; //Product Id

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);

echo $product->getName(); //Get Product Name
```

Note: Don't use objectManager directly

**With Factory Method**

```
<?php

  protected $product;  

  public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $product
    ) {
        $this->product = $product;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getProduct($id)
    {
        return $this->product->create()->load($id);
    }

}
```

Then call `getProduct` function in your phtml file

```
$productId = "10"; //Product Id
$product=$this->getProduct($productId);

echo $product->getName(); //Get Product Name
```

block and phtml link like this (add your block file path )

```
<block class="VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\YourBlockName" name="custom.data" template="VendoreName_ModuleName::yourfilname.phtml" >
```

Add this code your xml file may be help :-

```
<referenceContainer name="footer">
            <block class="VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\YourBlockName" name="custom.data" template="VendoreName_ModuleName::yourfilname.phtml" after="-"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: I just want to display same product name on product view page on footer part, look like breadcrumbs, can you help, thank you!

Comment: check my update answer may be help you

Answer (score 0):

**app\code\VendoreName\ModuleName\Block**

**ProductName.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Block;

use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;

class ProductName extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $registry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }
    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {
        return $this->registry->registry('current_product');
    }

}
```

**app\code\VendoreName\ModuleName\view\frontend\templates**

**getProduct.phtml**

```
$prd = $block->getCurrentProduct();
$product_entityid = $prd->getEntityId();
$product_sku = $prd->getSku();
$product_name = $prd->getName();
echo "<h1>".$product_name."</h1>";
```

**app\code\VendoreName\ModuleName\view\frontend\layout**

**catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
      <referenceContainer name="content">
        <referenceContainer name="columns">
            <block class="VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\ProductName" name="custom.data" template="VendoreName_ModuleName::getProduct.phtml" after="-" >
        </referenceContainer>
    </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```